# Woocommerce quickpay Not authorized: Not authorized to PUT /payments/:id/link

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, quickpay

I'm building a shop with `woocommerce` and I'm using `Quickpay`. So when I click the order-pay button I get the error:

```
Not authorized: Not authorized to PUT /payments/:id/link
```

does anybody know what that issue is about?

Answer (score 0):

this can be solved by logging in to Quickpay. The point "See/create payments" had a tick in "Create" column but not in "View" column. Set a tick in View Column. This should work and check your code:

/payments?order_id=x

This should solve your problem, for further information to the coding:

[Guide for API](https://learn.quickpay.net/tech-talk/api/services/?scope=merchant#GET-payments---format-)

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

there is a better way. In the quicpay manager. If you are using the API user. You can go to - Settings > Users > System users, click the API user, and then click Use template and find the system that you use.